Make Subiquity installer remove certain snap packages during installation?
How can I instruct the Subiquity installer to remove certain snap packages during installation of Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop?
I have attempted to do this using an autoinstall.yaml file placed on the ISO in the /preseed directory. However, the installer crashes with the error:
RuntimeError: source model has changed but autoinstall configuration already being applied

The autoinstall.yaml file has the following contents:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  interactive-sections:
    # Prompt the user during installation.
    - user-data
    - locale
    - refresh-installer
    - keyboard
    - network
    - ubuntu-pro
    - ubuntu-advantage
    - proxy
    - storage
    - identity
    - ssh
    - snaps
    - active-directory
    - codecs
    - drivers
    - timezone
    - updates
  late-commands:
    # Remove the following snaps.
    - ['curtin', 'in-target', '--target=/target', '--', 'snap', 'remove', '--purge', 'firefox']
    - ['curtin', 'in-target', '--target=/target', '--', 'snap', 'remove', '--purge', 'thunderbird']
    - ['curtin', 'in-target', '--target=/target', '--', 'snap', 'remove', '--purge', 'ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap']

I reference this file using subiquity.autoinstallpath=/cdrom/preseed/autoinstall.yaml in /boot/grub.cfg as follows. (I've also updated /boot/loopback.cfg similarly).
menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz subiquity.autoinstallpath=/cdrom/preseed/autoinstall.yaml --- quiet splash
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
}

I've validated the autoinstall.yaml file format using cloud-init schema --config-file autoinstall.yaml, and the layout seems file.
Please let me know if I am using the correct approach with the autoinstall.yaml file? Am I configuring it correctly?
Is there a better way to automatically remove default snaps during installation? (The Ubuntu Desktop installer, snapd-desktop-integration, is a snap package, so I can't just remove snapd from the squashfs file system and call it a day).
My requirement is that the instructions to remove the snaps must be on the ISO itself (which I why I have placed the autoinstall.yaml directly on the ISO and updated the ISO's /boot/grub.cfg file).
